FTP failure when using /usr/bin/ftp but wrosk using python module
I am trying to run FTP from my  shell script using /usr/bin/ftp, as below (I am sending these files to the Windows FTP server):
/usr/bin/ftp -v -n 10.23.23.34 <<FTP_SCRIPT > ${TMPDIR}/ftp.error 2>&1
   user "${USERNAME}" "${PASSWORD}"
   binary
   put "${TMPDIR}"/"${TAR_FILE}" "${TARGET}"
   quit
   FTP_SCRIPT

FTP is able to open connection to the server but hangs until i do a  ctrl c.

/usr/bin/ftp -v -n 10.23.23.34
^C++ signal_callback INT
++ i_error 'Received INT Signal .. exiting.'

I manually tried to connect to ftp server with usr/bin/ftp -v -n 10.23.23.34.
-connection was successful with user/password. Then tried to PUT or get but hangs again.
-if i give "ls" also it says:
ftp>
150:Opening ASCII mode data connection
hangs then...
However, i have python script which uses  Python library to the same FTP server and credentials  and FTP is successful.
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP(host, user, passwd)
   # Send file to server over ftp
   ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % rfile, fp)

what is the difference between two? How can i debug why data is not PUT/GET from the windows FTP server..

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry to say but there are so many misspelled and strange words in your question it can not be understood. Please try to correct.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].

sorry for the typo.
updated the description. FTP hangs when doing PUT/GET until i do a ctrl c.
I am running this in my ubuntu 20.04

Are you using pasv mode?

i am running ftp as usr/bin/ftp -v -n 10.23.23.34.  should i run with -p option to enable passive mode?
Am seeing this issue only for one ftp server. It works for all other ftp servers without -p.

Which shell are you using to run the script? Please check that the code formating in your question is correct - as written, the indentation of the here document is invalid at least in sh/bash (the final FTP_SCRIPT must be at the start of a line, unless the redirection operator is <<- in place of << when it may be indented by a TAB character)

Please edit your question and provide full output that the FTP command displays, including "PORT command successful" message (if any). If the Python FTP code displays any output, provide it as well for comparison.

While actual output from ftp command would be useful to verify the assumption, it is very probable that active mode FTP does not work between client and server in question.
The ftp command by default uses active mode, while Python FTP class - as per documentation - uses passive mode by default.
The reason why passive mode works and active does not is probably a badly configured firewall or router on either side of the connection, or somewhere in between.
As a workaround, try to use passive mode with the ftp command by specifying the -p parameter on the command line or using the passive command in the FTP script before any commands that transfer data (eg. put).

thanks for the answer.
I cannot make ftp to run in passive mode since this legacy code works for most of the ftp server except this one.
If i have to make active work and use the same /usr/bin/ftp -v -n 10.23.23.34 , does it mean we have to change any firewall or router settings  to make it work ?

running ftp in passive mode went through successfully. But if i want to run the ftp in active mode only what config do i need to change from client/server side to make it work?

Not knowing your network setup, I cannot answer what do you need to change. But this definitely seems to be a networking problem, so you know where you have to look.

ok thanks a lot for the help.
